# Get windows process start time

Tags: windows, go, process, operating-system

I know there is package like **[go-ps](http://github.com/mitchellh/go-ps)** to give us active running process in Windows, but this package doesn't have process start time and other information of process.

And I know in Windows power shell with this command I can get process start time.

```
Get-Process | select name, starttime
```

I don't want to execute command and get result the parse it, actually the main Idea is how to get process time with main Go packages like [**os**](https://golang.org/pkg/os/).

Comment: Have you looked at what [ProcessState.Sys](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#ProcessState.Sys) returns on Windows?

Comment: FFI into [GetProcessTimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocesstimes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [w32](https://github.com/gonutz/w32) package for this. I maintain this repository and you can ask to include new WinAPI functions by creating an issue or do it yourself and open a pull request.

Here is a sample of how you can get the current process' run time. We wait a second, ask for the time and the output is slightly higher than a second.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/gonutz/w32/v2"
)

func main() {
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    creation, _, _, _, ok := w32.GetProcessTimes(w32.GetCurrentProcess())
    if !ok {
        panic("GetProcessTimes failed")
    }
    fmt.Println("creation", creation.Time())
    fmt.Println("run time", time.Now().Sub(creation.Time()))
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but there is no `GetCurrentProcess` function

Comment: Sure, it was the last thing I added before answering this, to show you that this is not a dead repo, we can update it as needed. Just do a `go get -u github.com/gonutz/w32` to get the latest changes.

Note also that this example does not do what you did in your question, you might need EnumProcesses for that but it should work with the library. If you miss any other function, just issue it.

Comment: @ttrasn Hey, did you give it a try? I just updated the w32 library to use modules (like a lot of my other repos and the rest is soon to follow). See the updated code sample where it says `import "github.com/gonutz/w32/v2"` now.